# Do I need periods in parentheses for examples that include full sentences?

Tags: parenthesis, periods

it's hard to explain so here's a madeup example:

> I like Stackexchange because it has funny questions (e.g., “What is English?”), interesting comments (e.g., "You put the 'low' in 'clown.'") and weird editor comments (e.g., "This sounds like homework.").

As you can see, the examples include complete sentences and I find it weird to put periods there, particularly the last one. Are they necessary? Thanks.

Comment: Lose the e.g. inside parentheses.

Comment: No, you should not have a period inside parentheses unless you are putting a stand-alone sentence inside the parentheses. (For example, this sentence is inside parentheses.)  If the parentheses are inside of a sentence (for example, this sentence is inside the parentheses inside of another sentence) then it should not have a period.

Answer (score 0):

I like Stackexchange because it has funny questions such as “What is English?”, interesting comments such as "You put the 'low' in 'clown.'" and weird editor comments such as "This sounds like homework.".
OR
I like Stackexchange because it has funny questions (“What is English?”), interesting comments ("You put the 'low' in 'clown.'") and weird editor comments ("This sounds like homework.").

e.g. simply is not needed. It is obvious that the sentences are examples.

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally put complete sentences inside parentheses, so you don't normally need periods inside parentheses. If it is a complete sentence, you probably don't need the parentheses at all.

"This sounds like homework." is a complete sentence, so it needs a period. This is still true if it is placed inside quotation marks, and the quoted sentence is placed inside parentheses.

---

Note that, in the UK, a period is usually referred to as a full stop. The word period is used for intervals of time and for menstruation.